# Как расположить вводимый текст и placeholder от textarea на одной линии

Tags: html, css, input, textarea, placeholder

Не могу никак расположить вводимый текст в `textarea` и `placeholder` на одной линии. Текст печатается сверху от `placeholder`-а. В `input`- ах с этим проблем нет (не обращайте внимания на цвет и размер вводимого текста). Как можно это исправить?
Код дан снизу.

```css
.example {
display: flex;
 flex-direction: column;
}

.footer__input {
  width: 570px;
  height: 60px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 14px 0 14px 24px;
  background-color: #414141;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

.footer__textarea {
  height: 150px;
  margin-bottom: 32px;
  padding-top: 14px;
  padding-left: 24px;
  background-color #414141;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 16px;
}

::placeholder {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 32px;
  color: #cacaca;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
<input class="footer__input" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Фамилия, имя и&nbsp;отчество*">
<input class="footer__input" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Email*">
<textarea class="footer-form__text footer__textarea" name="message" placeholder="Сообщение" style="background-color: #414141"></textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант добавить в .footer__textarea - line-height: 32px